# Java normalize file path for external execution

Tags: java, file, process

I have this code:

```
StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder("ffmpeg -ac 1 -i ");
command.append(videoFile.getPath());
command.append(" ");
command.append(audioFile.getPath());
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.toString());
```

The problem is when the file (videoFile | audioFile) have a space character in their path, the process (ffmpeg) fail to execute.
My question is how can I fix the path for both Linux and Windows before executing the process ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `exec(String)`, use `exec(String[])` (from `Runtime`). The second form lets you supply all arguments individually, that way Java does not need to parse them further, and will not split on spaces.

Example:

```
  Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    new String[]{"ffmpeg", "-ac", "1", "-i",videoFile.getPath()), audioFile.getPath()}
  );
```

You should always use the second form if your arguments may contain spaces, otherwise your command may break.